# Cors error occurs while getting object from s3

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using Aws-sdk in my angular application.uploading and deleting files processes are working fine but when it comes to get file object from s3 bucket sometimes i get cors policy error . any solution to overcome this problem?
this is my bucket policy?

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "Etag"
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see that the bucket policy looks fine. Try to fix this on the client-side I mean in the angular application.

Here is a good guide,

https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/do-you-know-how-to-resolve-cors-issues-in-angular-9d818474825f

I don't recommend using '*' in the s3 configuration.

Comment: yes i have used that earlier but didnot work